# Generics Example Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and as a C# developer, when I want to re-use code (for a repository class), I could put it into a base class of type `<T>` to be able to do something like this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return Context<T>.GetAll();
}
```

If I need to do any custom logic, I could, of course, override the method in my 'User' repository.

In Ruby, I am familiar that you can do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

This will allow access to all methods in ApplicationController and it's parent classes. When using scaffolding, it generates the following method in each of my child classes:

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
  end
end
```

What I end up with is 10 classes that have the same method, but the only difference is 'User.all', 'Post.all', etc.

How would I make this method generic so I can put it in my ApplicationController class?

Thanks for any assistance you can provide to a Ruby on Rails newbie.

Comment: excellent question, I'm wondering the same thing

Comment: Just a thought: add a method in app controller called `load_all_records`. In it, determine the current controller name (`params[:name]`), strip off the controller part (so you're left with name of model), constantize and send the message `all` to the constantized class using `send` or `__send__`. Then call `load_all_records` in a before_filter for the desired actions in app controller itself. In controllers where you don't need the behavior, you can called `skip_before_filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to realize about the scaffolding code is that it can be abreviated, as such:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

unless you intend to deliver the view in another format, like json, html, pdf, the respond_to block is unnecessary. If you still feel the need to dry up this method, you could do something like

```
# app/controllers/concerns/autoload_records.rb

module AutoloadRecords
  included do
    before_action :load_records, only: :index
    before_action :load_record, only: [:create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end

  private
  def load_records
    @records = model_class.all
  end

  def load_record
    @record = model_class.find(params[:id])
  end

  def model_class
    klass = self.class.to_s[/\A(\w+)sController\Z/,1] #=> get the name of the class from the controller Constant
    Object.const_get(klass)
  end
end
```

and write your controller like

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include AutoloadRecords

  def index
    @records # => #<ActiveRecord::Relation[...]>
  end

  def show
    @record # => #<User ...>
  end

  def non_rest_action
    @record # => nil
    @records # => nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Using the above code, I get the following error `undefined method `all' for "Users":String` from Rails.

Comment: I also tried changing the 2nd line of code to: `@objs = eval "#{klass}.all"` and I get the following error: `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Users`

Comment: right, because the model is singular. i guess i'll actually have to go try it :\

Comment: Another thought: I find the fact that it's trying to find `Users` in `ApplicationController` a little disconcerting... Anyone know how to use eval to find it in the global scope?

Comment: @kelloti is right, it should be included in a module and not available to the application controller. I'm really not convinced this level of 'DRYness' is needed, nor does it seem exceptionally safe or recommended, but its cool you can do it, i guess.

Comment: @Jed - I'm not really a rubyist, but in .NET we frequently seek this sort of dryness. It only seems natural that ruby would let you write code this dry as well. And why does it seem unsafe?

Comment: Looking at the solution, I question if this solution is a good idea. I am also concerned about how thread-safe or performant doing a bunch of string concatenation is. It might be best to use mixins as Jesus recommended in another post.

Comment: @Brandon, you are doing a sql statement that selects all the records from the given table, I'm certain you will be hitting your head on the query, long before the concatenation performance of the string hurts your response time. Should be thread-safe though it was just off the top of my head.

Comment: @kelloti, except for some very basic apps and generic scaffolded models, you will generally not use the same action for each model. eg: @users = User.active. The DRY concept came out of ruby: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself and anytime you use 'eval' or 'instance_eval' you need to be concerned with safety. http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/eval_isnt_quite_pure_evil and eval makes it harder to test or track down problems.

Comment: @Jed, To me it seems like there should be a way to get the associated model for the child controller from the heap or use a helper class of type `module ControllerMethods<T>` and include it as such: `include ControllerMethods<User>`. The fact that there is no simple way to do this, to me, is a limitation of Rails or Ruby.

Comment: @Brandon: The lack of a method to infer the model name from the controller is a clue -- there is no relationship between models and controllers unless you define one. Eg. model `User` and controller `UsersController` is a common convention, but the MVC pattern implies that controllers and models do not have to be related, and in fact should know as little as possible about each other.

Comment: Please look below at the InheritedResources gem mentioned below. It's a much better solution in my mind than doing this.

Comment: @zetetic - I wouldn't care about being able to infer the `User` model as long as I could specify it as part of an include statement. This is very easy to do in a statically typed language like Java or C# and I was hoping for something similar in Ruby.

Comment: @gaustin - I will take a look at the InheritedResources gem. I am looking for something that doesn't highly obfuscate my code to keep it maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing an `eval` where you really don't want to be doing one. Check out Jose Valim's [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem. It provides the standard CRUD methods for all of your controllers and is quite sophisticated. It is also thoroughly tested so you don't have to worry about making sure your generic code operates as expected in all cases.

For details on how to use it see the GitHub page linked.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a simple solution could be to rely on mixins.

You define a module,

```
module MyModule 
   def my_index(klass)
     @elements = klass.all

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.xml  { render :xml => @elements }
     end
   end
end
```

Then, you have in your controller,

```
include MyModule
def index
   my_index(User)
end
```

Of course, you need to use @elements in your views. If you want a different variable name in each view you can do

```
   def my_index(klass, var_name)
     self.instance_variable_set(var_name, klass.all)
     ...
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several rails plugins that help to reduce this kind of duplication. This one was covered in railscast episode 230.

https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on my experience, you rarely end up with 10 index action looking like `@user = User.all`. If you know in advance that some actions between different models will be identical - well then may be it makes sense to  extract common logic. But then again may be these models are somehow connected? I wouldn't say in advance that Post and User will have identical index actions.
2. For a short method like this I wouldn't try to eleminate repetition because you may end up losing readability.